# Using multiple Laravel scopes in OR context

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a Subscription model which contain `start_date` and `end_date` attributes in my Laravel app. I have created two query scopes, scopeActive and scopeFuture to find active and future subscriptions (respectively).

I would like to know how I can build a query using both scopes in OR context, so that I can find any active or future subscriptions.

**Subscription Model**

```
/**
 * Scope a query to only include active subscriptions.
 *
 * @param \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder $query
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder
 */
public function scopeActive($query)
{
    return $query->where('start_date', '<', Carbon::now())
                 ->where('end_date', '>', Carbon::now());
}

/**
 * Scope a query to only include future subscriptions.
 *
 * @param \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder $query
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder
 */
public function scopeFuture($query)
{
    return $query->where('start_date', '>', Carbon::now());
}


public function business()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Business');
}
```

**Business Model**

```
.....
public function subscriptions()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Subscription');
}
```

**User Model**

```
public function business()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Business');
}
```

**Controller**

```
Subscription::active()->get();
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

### For static-context try:

```
$subscriptions = Subscription::query()
    ->active()
    ->orWhere(function ($query) {
        $query->future();
    })
    ->get();
```

> First call `query()` to prevent errors (because we may have a non-static method with "`active`" as name).

### Relation query <sup>(as requested in the comment)</sup>

```
$subscriptions = auth()->user()
    ->business()
    ->subscriptions()
    ->active()
    ->orWhere(function ($query) {
        $query->future();
    })
    ->get();
```

> **Note** that above we don't need to call `query()` (because it's not from static-context).

Comment: Could you provide an example of this when querying Subscriptions from a relationship? e.g. `Auth::user()->business->subscriptions()->get();`

Comment: @Imran added example in the answer. Also note use `business()` and not 'business'. Using it like you are will fetch the business and then get the subscriptions on it, using `business()` will not however and only the subscriptions get fetched from the database. I've also posted this in your other question.

Comment: Thanks Sandeesh, however the updated query returns `Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::subscriptions()` error. The relationship is definitely defined in the Business model.

Comment: Can you share the `business` relationship on user model and `subscriptions` relation on your business model. You can add it to your question. I'll check once.

Comment: @Imran i don't see anything wrong with your relationship. You can also try adding a hasmanythrough relationship to make things simpler. You can add this on user model `public function subscriptions()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Subscription', 'App\Business');
    }` and try to fetch subscriptions directly from user model

Comment: While this does work, I'd like to know why it won't work through Business relationship.

Comment: @Sandeesh Although I added an example answer, I followed your answer to get to my answer and awarded you points.  Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

```
Subscription::active()->orWhere( function($q){
            return $q->future() ;
        } )->get() ;
```

Answer (score 1):

Take advantage of params. You could try something like...

```
public function scopeCanceled($query, $scope = 'where')
{
    return $query->$scope('canceled_at');
}
```

then you can do for example `$query->canceled('orWhere')`

you can then de-uglify with:

```
public function scopeOrCanceled($query)
{
    return $this->scopeCanceled($query, 'orWhere');
}
```

example `$query->orCanceled()`

in general with scopes, i find it handy to always have some sort of optional value, to make things flexible

```
public function scopeApproved($query, bool $value = true)
{
    return $query->where('is_approved', $value);
}
```

adding a third param for this use case can then make sense

```
public function scopeApproved($query, string $scope = 'where', bool $value = true) {
    return $query->$scope('is_approved', $value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not trying to answer, just wanted to lay  down an example.

```
public function scopeVisable(Builder $builder){

    $builder->where(function($builder){
            $builder->orWhere(function($builder){
            $builder->isPublic();
        });
        $builder->orWhere(function($builder){
            $builder->isMine();
        });
    });

    return $builder;
}

public function scopeIsPublic(Builder $builder){

    $builder->whereIsPublic(true);

    return $builder;
}

public function scopeIsMine(Builder $builder){

    $user = app(CurrentUser::class);
    $builder->whereAddedByUserId($user->getKey());

    return $builder;
}
```

The builder's ->toSql() reveals:

`select * from channels where (('is_public' = ?) or ('added_by_user_id' = ?))`