# How to make main menu public in all controllers

Tags: laravel, controller

i have this code in controller

```
$Headercategory=Categories::where('status','1')->orderby('order')->get();
return view('front.home',['Headercategory'=>$Headercategory]
```

all my controlles will include "Headercategory" that mean i have to do same code with all controllers i have.

is there any way to make this code public in all project? without no need to add it in all controllers

Comment: you need scopes [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#writing-global-scopes). Here are some examples [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44098385/using-multiple-laravel-scopes-in-or-context), [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63010974/gracefully-exiting-laravel-scopes), [link3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29913412/laravel-global-scopes-with-joins)

Comment: is this a particular view that is rendering the menu? if so you could use a view composer to pass that data for that particular view ... if not you could use a view share

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand, you want to pass categories variable in your all blade file. You can do that easily from `/app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php` on boot method :

```
use View;

public function boot()
{
     $Headercategory = Categories::where('status','1')->orderby('order')->get();

     View::share(['Headercategory' => $Headercategory);
}
```

Now you can access `$Headercategory` anywhere from your blade